# Conversion from null-integer to pointer in comma list

Tags: c++, pointers, null, c++98

I know that in our modern world NULL and 0 are not best practices in operating with pointers, and according to cppreference:

> Pointer conversions A null pointer constant (see NULL), can be
>   converted to any pointer type, and the result is the null pointer
>   value of that type. Such conversion (known as null pointer conversion)
>   is allowed to convert to a cv-qualified type as a single conversion,
>   that is, it's not considered a combination of numeric and qualifying
>   conversions.

But why this code is not allowed and gcc with clang give me an error?

```
A* foo()
{
    return (bar(), NULL);
}
```

> error: invalid conversion from long int to A*

Comment: Do you mean allowed in gcc and error in clang?

Comment: Please post complete code. We don't know what `A` and `bar()` are, there could be an overloaded `operator,`, and there could even be macros to furher complicate the issue (as a matter of fact, `NULL` is a macro, so you cannot use it without an `#include`).

Comment: I suspect the compiler is converting NULL to the same type as bar's return type since it's part of a comma expression.  And then it has trouble converting that to an A pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that

```
(bar(), NULL)
```

is an expression using the [comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other).

> In a comma expression E1, E2, the expression E1 is evaluated, its result is discarded, and its side effects are completed before evaluation of the expression E2 begins (note that a user-defined operator, cannot guarantee sequencing).
>
> **The type, value, and value category of the result of the comma expression are exactly the type, value, and value category of the second operand, E2**. If E2 is a temporary, the result of the expression is that temporary. If E2 is a bit-field, the result is a bit-field.

So the type of `(bar(), NULL)` is being determined as a `long int` as that is the type of `NULL` So it is trying to convert a `long int` with the value of `NULL` to an `A*` which will fail.

If we changed the code to

```
A* foo()
{
    return NULL;
}
```

This will compile as the value of `NULL` is used and the value of `NULL` can be assigned to a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is presented in your question.

> A null pointer **constant** (see NULL), can be converted to any
>   pointer type, and the result is the null pointer value of that type.

`NULL` is constant, `bar(), 0` is not constant.

Just compare:

```
A* foo()
{
    return 0;
}
```

versus

```
A* foo()
{
    int v = 0;
    return v;
}
```

versus

```
A* foo()
{
    const int v = 0;
    return v;
}
```

Comment: In the last code snippet v is const yet it doesn't compile

Comment: It compiles by GCC C++98 (see question tags), but it does not compile by C++11.

Comment: and it makes sense. imagine code int a = std::rand(); const int c = a; A* f = c;